# Iterating a JSON string with maps in JS

Tags: javascript, json, loops, dictionary, format

I have been trying to iterate in a JSON that contains a map within a map for hours with no luck...

This is the JSON string:

```
 {
  "P31": {
    "wikibase-entityid": "Q16603799"
  },
  "P227": {
    "string": "1084653095"
  },
  "P1001": {
    "wikibase-entityid": "Q183"
  },
  "P1448": {
    "monolingualtext": "Verordnung über Sicherheit und Gesundheitsschutz bei der Verwendung von Arbeitsmitteln"
  },
  "P1813": {
    "monolingualtext": "Betriebssicherheitsverordnung"
  },
  "P7677": {
    "string": "betrsichv_2015"
  },
  "P580": {
    "time": "+2002-10-03T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "P2671": {
    "string": "/g/1224z0c0"
  },
  "P9696": {
    "string": "11477"
  }
}
```

Image for an easy visual reference:
[image]

Note: each property can have multiple values.

I basically want to create a loop inside which I've got access to the property (PXXX, first thing), the type of the property (key in the inner map) and the value of the property (value in the inner map).

I have tried to convert the string to a Map using "new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr))", "new Map(Object.entries(jsonStr))" and other with no luck.

Additionally, I tried to iterate inside it with a "for (var key in obj)" and with a "myMap.forEach((value_propertyInfo, key_propertyName) => {...}" without luck either.

Some times it looks like I am iterating char by char, while others simply throw an error saying that the map is not iterable.

Does anybody know what I should use instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You could structure your data as an array instead of an object - `[{id: "P31", type: "wikibase-entityid", value: "Q16603799"}, ...]` - it would make iterating it a lot simpler, and you could better maintain the order of entries in the array.

Comment: Do you have influence on the structure of the data?

Comment: Yes, I do! @ReinState

Comment: It looks like some SPARQL query of Wikidata ;-) How do you request the data?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I suppose that would make it way easier. I just didn't modify the original format @James Thanks

Comment: @ReinState close, it is a JSON download from a Wikidata URL like this: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.json but you are right, I can adapt it as well. However, I'd like to test first the other responses before changing the data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with `Map`. Just iterate over the data object, log the key, and then log over that property's object entries, and log the key, and the value.

```js
const data = {"P31":{"wikibase-entityid":"Q16603799"},"P227":{"string":"1084653095"},"P1001":{"wikibase-entityid":"Q183"},"P1448":{"monolingualtext":"Verordnung über Sicherheit und Gesundheitsschutz bei der Verwendung von Arbeitsmitteln"},"P1813":{"monolingualtext":"Betriebssicherheitsverordnung"},"P7677":{"string":"betrsichv_2015"},"P580":{"time":"+2002-10-03T00:00:00Z"},"P2671":{"string":"/g/1224z0c0"},"P9696":{"string":"11477"}};

for (const key in data) {
  console.log(key);
  const entries = Object.entries(data[key]);
  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! In case anybody else sees this: You might have to convert the string (formatted as json) to json. And I stored the first "key" in a variable so in the second "console.log" I would have all the relevant information at the same time. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the object properties and extract for each item propertyId, propertyName and propertyValue like this:

```
let o = //the object coming from the json

Object.keys(o).forEach( (propertyId) => {
    //I'm taking for granted that each item will contain one property only and that property will be what we are looking for
    let propertyType = Object.keys( o[propertyId] )[0];
    let propertyValue = o[propertyId][propertyType];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is really suboptimal. It uses variable property names, "PXXX" in the outer and the type in the inner objects. Ideally you have always fixed property names and only the values vary. The best would be this form of array and iteration

```js
a=[
[prop, type, value],
[prop, type, value], // {"prop": prop, "type": type, "value":value} is also good
...
]
for(const [prop, type, value] of a) handleProperty(prop, type, value);
```

We can nearly reach this by transforming the json string before parsing:

```js
s='{"P31":{"wikibase-entityid":"Q16603799"},"P227":{"string":"1084653095"},"P1001":{"wikibase-entityid":"Q183"},"P1448":{"monolingualtext":"Verordnung über Sicherheit und Gesundheitsschutz bei der Verwendung von Arbeitsmitteln"},"P1813":{"monolingualtext":"Betriebssicherheitsverordnung"},"P7677":{"string":"betrsichv_2015"},"P580":{"time":"+2002-10-03T00:00:00Z"},"P2671":{"string":"/g/1224z0c0"},"P9696":{"string":"11477"}}'

data=JSON.parse(s.replaceAll(':{',':[').replaceAll('":"','","').replaceAll('"}','"]'))
/* We now have
data={
prop:[type, value],
prop:[type, value],
...
}*/

for(const [prop,[type, value]] of Object.entries(data)) console.log(prop,type,value)
```

using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

If you don't want to transform the JSON string, you will have to use

Comment: The issue here is that a property can have multiple values of different types (if I am not wrong). Wouldn't your solution be an issue then?

Comment: Yes, the answer was specific to one value per property as in the example. On [Q42](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42)([JSON](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.json)) alone I see many properties with multiple values, like P69, P106, P108 and many others.

Comment: @Andy answer gave me what I needed with no need of reformatting the data and allowing multiple values per property. Nevertheless, thanks for your time and help!